# Proof Verification - All nonnegative reals have unique nonnegative square roots

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am asking simply to verify a proof since I don't think this is standard. In particular, this is a theorem in Apostol's Calculus book but I wanted to give it a go myself!

**Theorem**: $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}_{≥0} \exists! y \in \mathbb{R}_{≥0} \ni y^2 = c$.

**Proof**: The theorem is clear for $c=0$ so we consider only $c>0$. Let $P= \{x\in \mathbb{R}_{+} : x^2 < c\}$

$P$ is bounded above by $1+c$. $P$ is non-empty since if $c>1$, $1 \in P$ and if $0<c≤1$, $\frac{c}{2} \in P$. Hence $\exists y \in \mathbb{R}_{+} \ni \sup P = y$.

Suppose $y^2<c$ and let $k=c - y^2$. We show for some $\epsilon>0$, $0<2y\epsilon + \epsilon^2<k$; this contradicts $y$ being an upper-bound since then $y+\epsilon \in P$.

If $0<k<1$ and $y≥1$, set $\epsilon = \frac{k}{4y}$.
If $0<k<1$ and $0<y<1$ set $\epsilon = \frac{ky}{4}$. 
If $k≥1$ and $y≥1$, set $\epsilon = \frac{1}{4y^2}$.
If $k≥1$ and $0<y<1$, set $\epsilon = \frac{y}{4}$.

Suppose $y^2>c$. We show $y-\epsilon$ is an upper bound implying a contradiction. Let $k = y^2 - c$. Hence we show $0<2y\epsilon - \epsilon^2<k$ which implies $(y-\epsilon)^2>c$. Conveniently, we can use the same values for $\epsilon$ as before.

Thus $y^2 = c$. Uniqueness is clear since supremums are unique.

QED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct. But you don't need to list $4$ cases for the $\epsilon$. You can simply let $\epsilon = \min(y, \frac{k}{4y})$ so that 
$$2y\epsilon + \epsilon^2 = \epsilon (2y + \epsilon) \leqslant \frac{k}{4y} \cdot 3y < k.$$

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks for the help :)!